# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

Уже пол дня над ошибкой сижу. Все перепробовал. Вот укороченный код:
Ошибка: "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

```
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Form1.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;



            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Session" +
                " ([total_price]) values (@total_price );";


       cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
      {

           new OleDbParameter("@total_price", Convert.ToUInt64(textBox1.Text))
       });


            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();

        }
```

И не работает только походу для этой таблицы, потому что в других нет ошибок, хотя и данные оно не вставляет...
Потому скрин таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где client_id и worker_id - Через мастер подстановок связаны с другими таблицами(хз, может влияет).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что Session - зарезервированное слово. Попробуйте назвать таблицу по-другому
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266

Comment: Спасибо!!! Правда все равно таблица не заполняется, но хоть ошибок нет !

Comment: А все, ок. Убрал копирование бд.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить значение параметра с помощью:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_price", Convert.ToUInt64(textBox1.Text));
```